# Using VB.NET on visual studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am an absolute beginner in Visual basic and.NET development. I am trying to use a sample code I found online and play around with visual studio to run this web app

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class NumberToWords
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
<WebMethod(Description:="Gets the words for a Number", EnableSession:=False)> _
Public Function getWords(ByVal myNumber As String) As String
getWords = SpellNumber(myNumber)
End Function

'Main Function
Private Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber As String)
Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
Dim DecimalPlace, Count
Dim Place(9) As String
Place(2) = " Thousand "
Place(3) = " Million "
Place(4) = " Billion "
Place(5) = " Trillion "
' String representation of amount
MyNumber = Convert.ToString(MyNumber)
' Position of decimal place 0 if none
DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
'Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount
If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2))
MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
End If
Count = 1
Do While MyNumber <> ""
Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
Else
MyNumber = ""
End If
Count = Count + 1
Loop
Select Case Dollars
Case ""
Dollars = "zero Dollars"
Case "One"
Dollars = "One Dollar"
Case Else
Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
End Select
Select Case Cents
Case ""
Cents = " and zero Cents"
Case "One"
Cents = " and One Cent"
Case Else
Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
End Select
SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function
'Converts a number from 100-999 into text
Private Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber As String)
Dim Result As String
If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
'Convert the hundreds place
If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
End If
'Convert the tens and ones place
If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
Else
Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
End If
GetHundreds = Result
End Function

'Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text
Private Function GetTens(ByVal TensText As String)
Dim Result As String
Result = "" 'null out the temporary function value
If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then ' If value between 10-19
Select Case Val(TensText)
Case 10 : Result = "Ten"
Case 11 : Result = "Eleven"
Case 12 : Result = "Twelve"
Case 13 : Result = "Thirteen"
Case 14 : Result = "Fourteen"
Case 15 : Result = "Fifteen"
Case 16 : Result = "Sixteen"
Case 17 : Result = "Seventeen"
Case 18 : Result = "Eighteen"
Case 19 : Result = "Nineteen"
Case Else
End Select
Else ' If value between 20-99
Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
Case 2 : Result = "Twenty "
Case 3 : Result = "Thirty "
Case 4 : Result = "Forty "
Case 5 : Result = "Fifty "
Case 6 : Result = "Sixty "
Case 7 : Result = "Seventy "
Case 8 : Result = "Eighty "
Case 9 : Result = "Ninety "
Case Else
End Select
Result = Result & GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1)) 'Retrieve ones place
End If
GetTens = Result
End Function

'Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text
Private Function GetDigit(ByVal Digit As String)
Select Case Val(Digit)
Case 1 : GetDigit = "One"
Case 2 : GetDigit = "Two"
Case 3 : GetDigit = "Three"
Case 4 : GetDigit = "Four"
Case 5 : GetDigit = "Five"
Case 6 : GetDigit = "Six"
Case 7 : GetDigit = "Seven"
Case 8 : GetDigit = "Eight"
Case 9 : GetDigit = "Nine"
Case Else : GetDigit = ""
End Select
End Function
End Class
```

but I keep getting a load of errors. I have used the ASP.NET web application with VB as the language when starting a project. but my lack of knowledge shows that I can't get rid of these problems and make the program run. can you help me and tell me what needs to be added in order to have the application running with no issues.

Comment: I think you'll need to do some studying; this forum is more about specific issues and questions. Tips: Turn `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` both on. These will highlight syntax issues. Then use breakpoints and debug to step through your code and look at the states of various objects/variables to get an idea of what's happening. And I suggest not using a web app to start with - use a desktop form or something more manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue is what context, when and how to use that sample code?

That code looks to convert a number like 123.00 to "One Hundred and Twenty Three"

So, that's fine. But now the issue is WHEN/HOW/WHERE/WHAT context you want such code? We can't just take code and throw it against the wall. Like all software, the FIRST step before writing ONE like of code is to state the problem.

So, we could state the problem like this:

I want a text box on a form.
I enter a number into that text box.
I then run + use that sample code to convert the number into a text value, and then display that result in a 2nd text box.

So before you asked how to use that code, your failure here is not laying out the problem and describing what you attempted? Stack overflow can't give an answer to biology, or how to do brain surgery in one post. But you can ask how to use a scalpel to say cut a particular type of muscle tissue. SO ONLY works if you laid out the problem FIRST and then note where you run into trouble.

So, in your case without a first defined problem? how to use that code? Well we have ZERO clue how you want to use that code. maybe your supposed to create a PDF file with check amounts and you want that PDF to be downloaded, and then sent to a printer. Maybe you want that simple web form where you enter a number, and it is then displayed as text/words. There is a billion possible use cases for that code. And without some context to how/when/why/for what/ you going to use that code? Then we have next to nothing to go on. As I stated, this is a Q + A forum, not some university that going to teach you anymore then when you ask for cooking advice. no one going to come to your place and cook your dinner for you. But you can ask in a cooking forum for tips and ideas on how to cook eggs.

So, looking at that code? Well it has several parts. One part that JUMPS out is this is setup to be a web method. But wiring up JavaScript and web methods? That some rather advanced fancy stuff to start out with.

That's also why it near always better to define the problem, and what you trying to do. As opposed to say: how do I administer medicine to patients? (too broad). Or how do I use some code? (too broad - we have no idea what you trying to do here).

However, lets define the problem, and THEN see how we use that code. As noted, I would be going far beyond what is a practical approach for SO questions.

So, lets drop those two text boxes on a web form, and then use that code.

First, lets create a standard code module and put that code into that routine. So, to the project add->new item, and under visual base choose code module. We will thus have this:

Now I collapsed the routines - no need to be rude and post large amounts of code - especially when you already done so. So our code module will look like this:

[image]
Note how I DID add "public" to that first function. So change it from private to public.

Other then that?  Note how we took JUST the code - not the extra web method and extra stuff - we don't need all that stuff. So, we just pulled + dumped the code into a standard code module. (we did not include the extra bits and parts - we don't need them.

So, quite much the same as say VB6, or even how you would do this in MS-Access. We create a module (default was module1), and then put our needed functions and subs into that code module - works the same as VB6 or ms-access. So in VB6, or say ms-access? Well, it is typical to dump general routines such as this into that code module - and then you are free to call + use those routines anyplace you like.

Ok, so we saved the above - module1 (that's the default assuming this is the first module you created in that project.

Ok, now lets create a web form, drop in those two text boxes, and the button.

We will have this markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h2>Enter Number</h2>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Convert to text" />

        <br />
        <h2>Number as text result</h2>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtResult" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

If we run the page, we have this:

[image]

Ok, back to design mode. We double click on the button, and are now in the code editor.

We put this code in the button click:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    txtResult.Text = SpellNumber(txtNumber.Text)


End Sub
```

Now, if we run this, say enter 123 into the first text box, the results will look like this:

[image]